# Connecting Gdrive to headless server without a GUI interface through google-drive-ocamlfuse

Tags: google-drive-api

Can anyone suggest how to connect to a Google Drive server without a graphical interface using google-drive-ocamlfuse?

I'm following this guide: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/blob/beta/doc/Headless-Usage-%26-Authorization.md. However, it seems to only work in testing mode for a limited time. When I switch to "Production" mode in the "Publishing status," I receive the following error from Google:

Access blocked: xxx request is invalid

You can't sign in because backup_gd sent an invalid request. You can try again later or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are the developer of xxx, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request